# Search animal method for animal class

Tags: java, oop

I have a method and I am not quite sure what it does. I have a class Animal and an ArrayList of animals. I'm trying to understand it so I can eventually use something like that in the future. Could someone explain exactly what it does?

**This is my code:**

```
public Animal search(String name) {

    Animal result = null;
    for (Animal a : animals) {
        if (name.equals(a.getName())) {
            result = a;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That seems like very basic code, what is unclear about it? BTW: It would help if you specified the programming language, many people don't read questions without a known language tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line by line:

```
public Animal search(String name) {     //Method definition, parameter named name

    Animal result = null;               //Variable declaration to hold the result
    for (Animal a : animals) {          //for each loop, looping on all the animals and the current animal is stored in variable named a
        if (name.equals(a.getName())) { //check if current animal's name is equal to parameter's value
            result = a;                 //Yes, store it in result variable
        }
    }
    return result;                      //In the end return result, it could be null if no animal is found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a function that searches an array-like `animals` for an `Animal` instance by comparing the value of its `getName()` method with the string parameter `name` passed to the function.

The function looks at all elements in `animals` to return the last of the matches even though one may have already been found.

Answer (score 0):

It is a search method which will search for any animal in an ArrayList of Animal. Suppose if you pass 'Dog', then it will check in arraylist for any Animal with name 'Dog'

This Animal object would store result of the search. It would be the Animal object if found in arrayList, else it would be null.

```
 Animal result = null;
```

This for loop is for iterating over all the animals present in the animals arrayList

```
for (Animal a : animals) {

}
```

This will check the each animal if name of the animal name input is same as that of current Animal being iterated. If the `if` condition is true, it will store it in `result` object.

```
if (name.equals(a.getName())) { 
            result = a;                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Animal search(String name) {  //search method with name parameter

    Animal result = null;             
    for (Animal a : animals) {      //for loop retrieve single Animal object(a) per loop while (animals.size) from list of animals
        if (name.equals(a.getName())) {   //checks if 'Name' from Animal object is equal to name from search method if true it saves to result
            result = a;
        }
    }
    return result; //return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public Animal search(String name) {

```
Animal result = null;       //creating a result variable
for (Animal a : animals) {   
//for each animal (lets call them a in every iteration) in animals list
    if (name.equals(a.getName())) {           //if 'name' equals to a's name
        result = a;               // variable we created is now equal to 'a'
    }
}
return result;                                   //and returning the result.
```

}